# Ajax POST Spring json wrong character

Tags: json, ajax, spring, spring-boot

This is my user save controller.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST,consumes= {"application/json"})
@JsonDeserialize(as = Users.class)
public ResponseEntity addUser(@RequestBody String jsonUser){
    try{
       ///

    }catch (Exception e){
        ///
    }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

this is my ajax post

```
 var obj = '{'
            +'"name" : '+name+','
            +'"surname" : '+surname+','
            +'"username" : '+username+','
            +'"email" : '+email+','
            +'"password" : '+password+','
            +'}';

        $.ajax({
            url: "/users",
            method: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(obj) ,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);

            },
        });
```

If i post with postman, posted data is ok.But if i post with ajax, controller got this string

```
%22%7B%5C%22name%5C%22+%3A+asd%2C%5C%22surname%5C%22+%3A+asd%2C%5C%22username%5C%22+%3A+asd%2C%5C%22email%5C%22+%3A+asd%2C%5C%22password%5C%22+%3A+asd%2C%7D%22=
```

Comment: Don't build JSON by hand

Comment: I did but same problem is continue

Answer (score 0):

Pass javascript object inside `Json.stringify` instead of a string. Something like this:

```
var obj = {
    name: name,
    surname: surname,
    username: username,
    email:  email,
    password: password
};
```

instead of

```
var obj = '{'
        +'"name" : '+name+','
        +'"surname" : '+surname+','
        +'"username" : '+username+','
        +'"email" : '+email+','
        +'"password" : '+password+','
        +'}';
```

Since you are already passing a string in `Json.stringify`, it further escapes the double quotes and other characters.